# Use field in another templete with Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a component class where I am storing data on click. If the button is clicked I am storing data in an empty array. `clickedData = []`

I need to use this **clickedData** in different templete.  with 
`<div *ngIf ="clickedData">`. How can Do that ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thanks thats all i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You must use a shared service for it.

**sharedService.ts**

```
export class sharedservice(){
  public clickData: any[] = [];

  store(data){
    this.clickData=data;
  }

  getData(){
    return this.clickData;
  }
}
```

**2)** import & register the service in root module.

```
import {sharedservice} from 'relativepath';

  NgModule({
     imports:[...]
     ...
     providers: [sharedservice]
  })
```

**3)** inject the service in targeted component.

```
import {sharedservice} from 'relativepath';

export class AppComponent{
   constructor(private ss: sharedservice){}
}
```

**4)** use ss variable in template as shown (eg appcomponent.html)

```
   <button (click)="ss.store(whatever_data_you_want_to_store)"> save </button>
```

**5)** in other component html , use it like below,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ss.getData()">...</div> //don't forget to inject into constrictor
```